# compile error "type or namespace name could not be found" but available through intellisense auto-complete in code?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a C# MVC app.  I've added a NuGet package reference which has the following object:

```
MyCorp.Security.Framework.Components.User
```

I have a reference to this User object in my MVC app and the intellisense/auto-complete picks it up as well but when I rebuild the app I get a compile error:

> "The type or namespace name 'MyCorp' could not be found"

I tried Clean/Rebuild but I still get the error. Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: You may have the package reference but that does not necessarily mean that the _DLL reference_ was added to your project

Comment: Type or object? How are you trying to access it?

Comment: @maccettura I verified that the expected dll references display in the References list

Comment: @user10067458 ok, well we are going to need more info then.  Include a [MCVE] with your question

Comment: @itsme86 the code is referencing the object in the nuget package via a using directive as well as a fully qualified object reference as a method return type

Comment: Please add the code to your question. Or at least representative enough code that we can see what's going on.

Comment: Maybe this reflects a version compatibility issue. The NuGet package target framework is 4.6.1 whereas the MVC app that I'm attempting to add the NuGet package to has a target framework of 4.5.2. VS did not return any type of version incompatibility error but I think I had a similar issue a few months ago and when I set the versions to be the same then the issue went away.

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to be able to reference assemblies that have a higher version of the framework than the application.